FileReader returns garbage after a certain number of files in mobile safari
Been really stumped by this problem.  I've searched the web and haven't found traces of info on it, but I believe it is a widespread issue.
See the HTML in this post.  If I select more than 350 (the bounding value works for my iPhone, but it may vary based on device) photos the first 350 will upload just fine.  For photos after 350 each one will fail.  When this fails, the data returned is what appears to be an empty plist and the FileReader doesn't error.  Here is a sample of the bytes returned when it fails (appears to be an empty plist):
"bplist00�
X$versionY$archiverT$topX$objects��_NSKeyedArchiver�    Troot��U$null$)27ILQSU["

So, the question is:  Is this a known issue I just haven't found Apple's documentation for?  Is there a way to work around this without putting an arbitrary limit on the number of files you can select?
The HTML is below.  I hosted it somewhere and debugged from my iPhone tethered to my Mac.  I am looking at the image header to avoid dumping out more bytes than necessary and overloading the debugger console.  I only log the contents of the first failure, but believe that all failure have the same contents.
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tester</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="selectButton">Select Photos</button>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" accept="image/*"  multiple>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('selectButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
    });
    
    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      const files = event.target.files;
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        testImage(file);
      }
    });
    
    var savedOutput = false;
    
    function testImage(file) {
      var _reader = new window.FileReader(),
        _fn = file.slice || file.mozSlice || file.webkitSlice || function() {
          return;
        },
        _slice = _fn.call(file, 0, 3);
    
      _reader.onloadend = function(_evt) {
        var _isValid = false,
          _bytes;
        if (!_evt.currentTarget.error) {
          _bytes = new window.Uint8Array(_evt.currentTarget.result);
    
          if (
            (_bytes[0] == 0xFF && _bytes[1] == 0xD8 && _bytes[2] == 0xFF) || //Check for jpg
            (_bytes[0] == 0x42 && _bytes[1] == 0x4D) || //Check for BMP
            (_bytes[0] == 0x89 && _bytes[1] == 0x50 && _bytes[2] == 0x4E) //Check for png
          ) {
            _isValid = true;
          } else {
            if (_bytes[0] == 0xFF && _bytes[1] == 0xD8 && _bytes[2] == 0xFF) {
              _isValid = true;
            }
          }
    
          if (_bytes[0] == 0x00 && _bytes[1] == 0x00 && _bytes[2] == 0x00) { //Check for heic
            _isValid = true;
          }
        }
    
        console.log('File: ' + file.name + ' is a JPEG: ' + _isValid);
    
        if (savedOutput === false && _isValid === false) {
          savedOutput = true;
    
          const decoder = new TextDecoder();
          const text = decoder.decode(_bytes);
          console.log('Failed Output: ', text);
        }
      }
    
      _reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I have tried this from more involved applications and it always fails.  The failure seems related to file access.

Are you getting the expected filename in the first console.log()?

@Barmar Yes, it is getting the expected URLs for the files.

You are facing this problem which might be possible due to 2 main reasons. Firstly, mobile safari might have a memory limit for handling files and once that limit is reached it start giving incomplete data. Secondly, it might also be possible that file reader might not be optimized to handle large batches of files on mobile devices.
SO, what you can do is that insted of processing all the file together at the same time you can try to make it possible with throttling mechanism to limit the number of files being processed at the same time.
I have written one code which is working fine in my device. I am listing it below try it with your solution and in case of any doubts let me know.
Note: This is a JavaScript code so attach it with your html code.
document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  const files = event.target.files;
  let index = 0;
  const batchSize = 50;

  function processBatch() {
    for (let i = 0; i < batchSize && index < files.length; i++, index++) {
      const file = files[index];
      testImage(file);
    }

    if (index < files.length) {
      setTimeout(processBatch, 500);
    }
  }

  processBatch();
});

function testImage(file) {
  var _reader = new window.FileReader(),
    _fn = file.slice || file.mozSlice || file.webkitSlice || function() {
      return;
    },
    _slice = _fn.call(file, 0, 3);

  _reader.onloadend = function(_evt) {
    var _isValid = false,
      _bytes;
    if (!_evt.currentTarget.error) {
      _bytes = new window.Uint8Array(_evt.currentTarget.result);

      if (
        (_bytes[0] == 0xFF && _bytes[1] == 0xD8 && _bytes[2] == 0xFF) ||
        (_bytes[0] == 0x42 && _bytes[1] == 0x4D) ||
        (_bytes[0] == 0x89 && _bytes[1] == 0x50 && _bytes[2] == 0x4E)
      ) {
        _isValid = true;
      } else {
        if (_bytes[0] == 0xFF && _bytes[1] == 0xD8 && _bytes[2] == 0xFF) {
          _isValid = true;
        }
      }

      if (_bytes[0] == 0x00 && _bytes[1] == 0x00 && _bytes[2] == 0x00) {
        _isValid = true;
      }
    }

    console.log('File: ' + file.name + ' is a JPEG: ' + _isValid);

    if (_isValid === false) {
      const decoder = new TextDecoder();
      const text = decoder.decode(_bytes);
      console.log('Failed Output: ', text);
    }
  }

  _reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}


I'm afraid this doesn't work Naveen.  I start getting these failures after I've had 371 successes.

Not sure but @Naveen might be onto something, however propsed solution is using setTimeout which might flood the memory slowly before GC kicks in. To correctly test the idea:

I am using async iterators to process files asynchorously, but one by one without overwhelming the buffer and event loop
I am reusing the same reader object instead of creating new ones, which might help.

I might have syntax errors, if in your browser Promise.withResolvers() does not exist, use the old school method of asigning resolver to a variable in the upper scope.


<html>

<head>
  <title>Tester</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="selectButton">Select Photos</button>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" accept="image/*" multiple>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('selectButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
    });

    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', async function(event) {
      const files = Array.from(event.target.files),
            dt = new DataTransfer();
      files.forEach(file => dt.items.add(file));
      processFiles(dt);
    });
    
    async function processFiles(dt) {
      for await (const iter of testImage(dt.files)) {
        dt.items.remove(0);
        console.log(`index ${iter} is done!`);
      }
    }

    var savedOutput = false;

    async function* testImage (files) {
      const _reader = new window.FileReader(),
        _fn = file.slice || file.mozSlice || file.webkitSlice || function() {
          return;
        };
      let len = files.length, file, fileIndex = 0;
      let {
        promise: pro,
        resolve: res,
        reject: rej
      } = Promise.withResolvers();
      _reader.onloadend = function(_evt) {
        const _slice = _fn.call(file, 0, 3);
        var _isValid = false,
          _bytes;
        if (!_evt.currentTarget.error) {
          _bytes = new window.Uint8Array(_evt.currentTarget.result);

          if (
            (_bytes[0] == 0xFF && _bytes[1] == 0xD8 && _bytes[2] == 0xFF) || //Check for jpg
            (_bytes[0] == 0x42 && _bytes[1] == 0x4D) || //Check for BMP
            (_bytes[0] == 0x89 && _bytes[1] == 0x50 && _bytes[2] == 0x4E) //Check for png
          ) {
            _isValid = true;
          } else {
            if (_bytes[0] == 0xFF && _bytes[1] == 0xD8 && _bytes[2] == 0xFF) {
              _isValid = true;
            }
          }

          if (_bytes[0] == 0x00 && _bytes[1] == 0x00 && _bytes[2] == 0x00) { //Check for heic
            _isValid = true;
          }
        }

        console.log('File: ' + file.name + ' is a JPEG: ' + _isValid);

        if (savedOutput === false && _isValid === false) {
          savedOutput = true;

          const decoder = new TextDecoder();
          const text = decoder.decode(_bytes);
          console.log('Failed Output: ', text);
        }
        res(fileIndex++)
      }
      while (len--){
        file = files[0];
        _reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        yield pro;
        ({
          promise: pro,
          resolve: res,
          reject: rej
        } = Promise.withResolvers());
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>




PS:
This looks like a bug in safari so I incorporated DataTransfer constructor to pass the files down to a function unrelated to the scope of the change event listener. And as I process the files, as a last effort, I am shifting the array of files by calling dt.items.remove(0) with the intention of freeing memory


From a Javascript perspective, I get your theory, Ibrahim.  That said, it doesn't resolve the issue.  I think there is an assumption here that this is a memory issue.  I don't see any concrete signs that is the case.  This type of solution is an optimization for sure, but it isn't stopping the problem.  I'm still thinking this is a bug in iOS Safari.

is the file number fixed like 370 or something or does it change from phone to phone? If the number is fixed it could suggest a bug, if not I guess more of a memory issue. In both cases, can't you cap the uploaded file nr to something like 200 and then set input.value = null and display a warning? Or even better, do Array.from(input.files), then devide the array to bits and map them to DataTransfer and finally create dynamic input elements and set their files property to DataTransfer.files ??

Also, I wonder what happens if we were to filter files > 5 Megapixels and pass the within the loop ? The other thing is to replace evt.currentTarget with this, just incase if evt gets GCed due to a bug or something

I haven't been able to run my test code through another device directly.  I know (for certain) this manifests on other devices and is not a symptom of only my phone.  For my phone, the number of files seems to be consistent per iteration of tests.  The batch of photos hasn't seemed to matter, but I haven't tried to find the lower bound using different batches.
It always seems to return an empty plist.  No sign of error, just an empty plist instead of an image.

I slightly modified the answer to include DataTransfer and remove the file blob objects as I process the. Given that average iOS safari is given 0.5Gb memory, even just having the blobs without reading could be an issue, which this solution "might" help. PLease be mindful of syntax error I might have but you get the idea



<html>

<head>
  <title>Tester</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="selectButton">Select Photos</button>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" accept="image/*" multiple>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('selectButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
    });

    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', async function(event) {
      const files = Array.from(event.target.files),
            dt = new DataTransfer();
      files.forEach(file => dt.items.add(file));
      processFiles(dt);
    });
    
    async function processFiles(dt) {
      for await (const iter of testImage(dt.files)) {
        dt.items.remove(0);
        console.log(`index ${iter} is done!`);
      }
    }

    var savedOutput = false;

    async function* testImage (files) {
      const _reader = new window.FileReader(),
        _fn = file.slice || file.mozSlice || file.webkitSlice || function() {
          return;
        };
      let len = files.length, file, fileIndex = 0;
      let {
        promise: pro,
        resolve: res,
        reject: rej
      } = Promise.withResolvers();
      _reader.onloadend = function(_evt) {
        const _slice = _fn.call(file, 0, 3);
        var _isValid = false,
          _bytes;
        if (!_evt.currentTarget.error) {
          _bytes = new window.Uint8Array(_evt.currentTarget.result);

          if (
            (_bytes[0] == 0xFF && _bytes[1] == 0xD8 && _bytes[2] == 0xFF) || //Check for jpg
            (_bytes[0] == 0x42 && _bytes[1] == 0x4D) || //Check for BMP
            (_bytes[0] == 0x89 && _bytes[1] == 0x50 && _bytes[2] == 0x4E) //Check for png
          ) {
            _isValid = true;
          } else {
            if (_bytes[0] == 0xFF && _bytes[1] == 0xD8 && _bytes[2] == 0xFF) {
              _isValid = true;
            }
          }

          if (_bytes[0] == 0x00 && _bytes[1] == 0x00 && _bytes[2] == 0x00) { //Check for heic
            _isValid = true;
          }
        }

        console.log('File: ' + file.name + ' is a JPEG: ' + _isValid);

        if (savedOutput === false && _isValid === false) {
          savedOutput = true;

          const decoder = new TextDecoder();
          const text = decoder.decode(_bytes);
          console.log('Failed Output: ', text);
        }
        res(fileIndex++)
      }
      while (len--){
        file = files[0];
        _reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        yield pro;
        ({
          promise: pro,
          resolve: res,
          reject: rej
        } = Promise.withResolvers());
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>



